# mac OS: ssh can't connect, even though sshd is listening and firewall is off?

Tags: osx, firewall

[Update -- Solved(?): See my answer below w/ my solution.  I'm still not sure why my symptoms (seem to have) changed from timing-out-entirely to taking-3-min-before-succeeding, though, which is what let me debug & find a workaround.]

When I try to ssh to my mac OS machine, it times out (as if nothing was listening to the port -- telnet'ing to port 22 also times out).  I *can* ping the machine successfully, so the network connection seems plausible, and I *can* ssh from the target machine to itself (localhost), so it is actually listening to port 22.  In fact, I can't telnet in to *any* port on that machine.

[add'l fact: I set up a web-server on port 8080, and likewise I can't connect to it from other machines, but I can confirm it really is listening to the port.  So it seems this is a network/port/firewall issue, and nothing ssh-specific.]

System Preferences looks okay (Sharing has Remote Login turned on for all users, and Firewall Options confirms "Remote Login(SSH)" is "Allow incoming connections" [(screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybj0X.jpg).  And launchctl seems to show that sshd is running.

I can go *from* that machine to another mac OS machine I have -- so it doesn't seem to be a router problem either [although: one machine is connected via ethernet, and the troublesome machine is connected via wireless].  As far as I can tell, I have both macs configured the same way.

Everything was working fine a couple weeks ago; I've installed a system update since then.  Maybe I've changed some system-setting in the mean time; I don't remember changing anything.  (The only other difference, as mentioned: one machine is connected to my router by ethernet, the other by wireless.)

Evidence that the machine ("tropic") is indeed listening to port 22 with sshd: it can see itself via localhost:

```
tropic> telnet localhost 22
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
```

and also `sudo launchctl list com.openssh.sshd` prints about 20 lines that look the same as a "correct" version on somebody else's post.

BUT when trying to connect from another machine ("equator"):

```
equator> ssh -vvv tropic.local
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/ibarland/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "tropic.local" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to tropic.local [192.64.0.3] port 22.
ssh: connect to host tropic.local port 22: Operation timed out
```

The network connection is okay:

```
equator> ping -c 2 tropic.local
PING tropic.local (192.64.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.64.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=17.424 ms
64 bytes from 192.64.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=19.654 ms

--- tropic.local ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 17.424/18.539/19.654/1.115 ms
```

Other things I've tried/verified: *I've turned off the firewall entirely* (on both computers), and I have tried *disabling my router's firewall* -- none of those made any difference.  Both sides are running the same version of ssh.  Both have been re-booted; I've made sure both have the latest system-update.

I've been hitting my head against this wall all afternoon; any insight, debugging-strategies, or other suggestions would be appreciated.  (I couldn't find any system-log messages generated by the port-listener, if there are any.)

Comment: Try turning your firewall off again and telnetting to the machine.  It sounds like you may need to enable the sshd-keygen-wrapper setting but that wouldn't make sense if it still didn't work with the firewall completely disabled.  It could also be a permission issue with your $HOME/.ssh directory and/or the files in it.   Make sure you own them and have the proper permissions to them.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this was (the entire) problem, but I solved an issue related to timeouts:

(a) A solution -- or at least a workaround -- was to edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host tropic
    HostName 192.168.1.4
```

(presumably this change would also work in `~/ssh/` without needing root privileges)

(b) the problem was a very-long (~3min) ssh timeout: `ssh -vvv` revealed that it was trying to connect twice using a MAC address; when it finally got around to trying an IP address it connected quickly.  [Though my question from 2 weeks ago seems to have been *failing* with a timeout after a few minutes; not sure how that was different when I revisited the problem this morning, when would eventually connect but only after several minutes.]

(c) Sadly, this replicates IP-addrs I also specify in `/etc/hosts` -- perhaps adding info to that file had triggered some of my issues?

(d) Fwiw, my problem was NOT solved via changing `ssh_config` lines regarding `GSSAPIAuthentication` or `GSSAPIDelegageCredentials`, nor by changing `sshd_config`'s option `UseDNS`.

Comment: SSH cannot connect with a MAC address. It does not run on a protocol that uses MAC addresses. However, it may have been trying to connect with an **IPv6** address (which is considerably longer than a MAC address, but some parts can be omitted). If DNS returned an IPv6 address but the IPv6 connection failed (e.g. due to incomplete IPv6 support or due to a firewall blocking it), specifying an explicit IPv4 address would indeed solve the problem. In this case, another solution that doesn't hard-code the address would be `AddressFamily inet`.